# Does a polynomial time shortest path algorithm exist given that both source and target verteces are reachable from a negative cycle?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, shortest-path, np

I'm not asking for an algorithm to check the existence of a negative cycle in a graph(Bellman Ford or Floyd Warshall can do that), rather whether or not there exists a polynomial time algorithm to find the shortest path between two points when the graph contains at least one negative cycle that is reachable from the source vertex and the target vertex can be reached from the negative cycle.

Comment: Then the shortest path has length -infinity, right?

Comment: According to the definition of path, it can not contain the same vertex more than once.

Comment: See http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17462

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a path (no repeating vertices) then this problem is NP hard.
You can reduce longest path problem to this one by simply multiplying weights by -1.

The main difference between classical (only positive weights on edges) shortest path (which is in P) and longest path problem (which is NP-complete) is following:
All polynomial shortest path algorithms are basically calculating shortest walk, but since you have positive weight on edges, the shortest walk is also shortest path (repeating edges does not decrease the length of walk). 
In longest path problem you have to somehow check for uniqueness of vertices on the path.

When you have negative cycle, then the Bellman-Ford algorithm calculates the length of the shortest **walk** which has at most N edges.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between shortest path(P) and longest path(NP Hard) problem? Why are they in different classes?

Comment: We are not able to find the shortest path in polynomial time in a graph with negative cycle. Then how is it that shortest path problems are in class P?

Comment: That's it I guess, this problems require the edge weights to be non-negative. Thanks.